# logstash how to disable "Dissector mapping, pattern not found" error in logstash-plain.log

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

i have log with lines in two formats.

```
aaa [bbb] [ccc] ddd eee
aaa [bbb] fff ggg [ccc] ddd eee
```

I've successfully use next logstash filter config to parse them.

```
filter {
 dissect {
    mapping => { "message" => "%{field1} [%{field2}] [%{field3}] %{message}" }
  }
  if "_dissectfailure" in [tags] {
    dissect {
       remove_tag => [ "_dissectfailure" ]
       mapping => { "message" => "%{field1} [%{field2}] %{stuff} [%{field3}] %{message}" }
    }
  }
}
```

All works as expected - lines without "fff ggg" matches with first dissect, lines with "fff ggg" don't matches with first dissect -> got tag "_dissectfailure" and successfully matches with second dissect (i see that field "stuff" appeared in the event and event don't have "_dissectfailure" tag )

But logstash complains in logstash-plain.log about first dissect:

```
[2019-09-04T20:14:06,901][WARN ][org.logstash.dissect.Dissector] Dissector mapping, pattern not found {"field"=>"message", "pattern"=>"%{field1} [%{field2}] [%{field3}] %{message}", "event"=>{"input"=>{"type"=>"log"}, "@timestamp"=>2019-09-04T17:13:50.269Z, "tags"=>["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "_dissectfailure"], "message"=>"aaa [bbb] fff ggg [ccc] ddd eee", }}
```

Please, help to get rid of this meaningless warnings and write such warning if only no dissect matches at all ?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html#using-conditionals) in you configuration, using a regex like `\[.*\] \[.*\]`. If it match, use the first dissect, if not the second.

Comment: i don't want do regexp - i need fast processing, that's why i use dissect instead grok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's old, but for anyone else coming across this:

```
    curl -XPUT 'localhost:9600/_node/logging?pretty' -H 'Content-Type:
    application/json' -d'
    {
        "logger.org.logstash.dissect.Dissector" : "ERROR"
    }
    '
```